# Page not found (404) No Product matches the given query

Tags: python, django

Page not found (404)
“C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\Miniproject\cake_studio\add_to_cart\1” does not exist
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_to_cart/1
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve

trying to add  product in to the cart, getting this error and not get correct data for my website

Comment: could you provide your code too, we can understand what's causing the problem